# Spring boot 2.0.X properties exceptionhandler response ascii?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ascii, bean-validation, exceptionhandler

everybody,i am using boot 2.0.x,project encoding and charset are UTF-8,
    request and response as same,but when using bean validation 2,
    to convert error msg,it shows ascii?
1:defined a bean such as BeanValidation.java:

```
@Data
public class BeanValidation implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6265504102271769397L;
    @Email(message = "{bv2.email.invalid}")
    @NotEmpty(message = "{bv2.email.required}")
    private String email;
}
```

2:using global exception handler:

```
    @RestControllerAdvice
public class GenericExceptionHandler 
    extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
    implements ErrorController{
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid1(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers,HttpStatus status,WebRequest request) {
        BindingResult br = ex.getBindingResult();
        List<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
        br.getFieldErrors().forEach(fe -> {
            errorList.add(fe.getField() + ":" + fe.getDefaultMessage());
        });
        br.getGlobalErrors().forEach(ge -> {
            errorList.add(ge.getObjectName() + ":" + ge.getDefaultMessage());
        });
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), errorList);
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
    }
}
```

3:define ValidationMessages.properties:

```
bv2.email.invalid = mail address is invalid,邮件地址无效!
bv2.email.required = mail address is required,邮件地址为必填项!
```

4:write controller to handle request:

```
@PostMapping("/bv2")
public Boolean jsr380(@Valid @RequestBody BeanValidation bv2) {
    return null == bv2 ? false : true;
}
```

5:start application and request via Postman with request parameter:
http://localhost:12345/contextPath/bv2,
request data:

```
{"email":"email address"}
```

response result:

```
{
            "timestamp": "2018-09-22T01:50:09.729+0000",
            "status": "400",
            "error": "Bad Request",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "defaultMessage": "mail address is invalid,é\u0082®ä»¶å\u009c°å\u009d\u0080æ\u0097 æ\u0095\u0088!",
                    "objectName": "beanValidation",
                    "field": "email",
                    "rejectedValue": "email address",
                    "bindingFailure": false,
                    "code": "Email"
                }
            ],
            "message": "Bad Request",
            "path": "/contextPath/bv2"
        }
```

6. it response success,but it encode ascii automaticly,so my question is:
               "defaultMessage": "mail address is invalid,é\u0082®ä»¶å\u009c°å\u009d\u0080æ\u0097 æ\u0095\u0088!",

when i using simpled chinese,it appears such as ascii code,
how to show or decode to normal such as:

```
mail address is invalid,邮件地址无效!
        mail address is required,邮件地址为必填项!
```

thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved it as a global way:

```
@Configuration
```

public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{

```
@Override
public Validator getValidator() {
    return validator();
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return validator;
}

/**
 * @title:messageSource:base name sequence:i18n and bean validation use this
 * [baseName]_[language]_[script]_[region]_[variant]
 * [baseName]_[language]_[script]_[region]
 * [baseName]_[language]_[script]
 * [baseName]_[language]_[region]_[variant]
 * [baseName]_[language]_[region]
 * [baseName]_[language]
 * @return MessageSource
 * @create 2018-09-25 09:32:24
 * @author:elf
 * @since:1.0.0
 */
@Bean
public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    String[] baseNameArray = {
        "classpath:i18n/msg",
        "classpath:i18n/bvMsg",
        "classpath:i18n/commonMsg",
    };
    source.setBasenames(baseNameArray);
    source.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
    return source;
}
```

}

bvMsg.properties under src/main/resources/i18n/bvMsg

```
bv2.price.min = 最低价格是666!
bv2.price.positive = 价格必须是正数!

bv2.email.invalid = 邮件地址无效!
bv2.email.required = 邮件地址为必填项!
```

response,it works as follows:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-09-25T07:05:03.420+0000",
"status": "400",
"error": "Bad Request",
"errors": [
    {
        "codes": [
            "Positive.beanValidation.price",
            "Positive.price",
            "Positive.java.lang.Integer",
            "Positive"
        ],
        "arguments": [
            {
                "codes": [
                    "beanValidation.price",
                    "price"
                ],
                "arguments": null,
                "defaultMessage": "price",
                "code": "price"
            }
        ],
        "defaultMessage": "价格必须是正数!",
        "objectName": "beanValidation",
        "field": "price",
        "rejectedValue": "-333",
        "bindingFailure": false,
        "code": "Positive"
    },
    {
        "codes": [
            "Email.beanValidation.email",
            "Email.email",
            "Email.java.lang.String",
            "Email"
        ],
        "arguments": [
            {
                "codes": [
                    "beanValidation.email",
                    "email"
                ],
                "arguments": null,
                "defaultMessage": "email",
                "code": "email"
            },
            [],
            {
                "arguments": null,
                "defaultMessage": ".*",
                "codes": [
                    ".*"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "defaultMessage": "邮件地址无效!",
        "objectName": "beanValidation",
        "field": "email",
        "rejectedValue": "fdsaomc.com",
        "bindingFailure": false,
        "code": "Email"
    },
    {
        "codes": [
            "Min.beanValidation.price",
            "Min.price",
            "Min.java.lang.Integer",
            "Min"
        ],
        "arguments": [
            {
                "codes": [
                    "beanValidation.price",
                    "price"
                ],
                "arguments": null,
                "defaultMessage": "price",
                "code": "price"
            },
            "666"
        ],
        "defaultMessage": "最低价格是666!",
        "objectName": "beanValidation",
        "field": "price",
        "rejectedValue": "-333",
        "bindingFailure": false,
        "code": "Min"
    }
],
"message": "Bad Request",
"path": "/contextPath/bv2"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

As my experience, you can do this in file 'xxx.properties'

`bv2.email.invalid = mail address is invalid,é\u0082®ä»¶å\u009c°å\u009d\u0080æ\u0097 æ\u0095\u0088!`

Answer (score 0):

Define default encoding type in properties file.

Try using

```
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
```

in application.properties file.

Comment: i tried to use   http:
    encoding:
      force: true
      enabled: true
      charset: UTF-8
      force-request: true
      force-response: true
  messages:
    encoding: UTF-8

Comment: yes you have to enable encoding utf-8..by any of the ways you can do the same.

Comment: i used request/response.charset,message.encoding,HttpMessageConvert to UTF-8,not work;

property file is expected to be encoded as ISO-8859-1,
and i just use use unicode escape to resolving this problem,

bv2.email.invalid = mail address is invalid,\u90ae\u4ef6\u5730\u5740\u65e0\u6548!
it works now:"defaultMessage": "mail address is invalid,邮件地址无效!"